# How do I use SF symbols in my Core Data model?

Tags: core-data, swiftui, sf-symbols

I want to be able to have my iOS app use SF symbols and store them in my `Entity` attribute in my `Core Data` model. I’m guessing I need to use the `Binary Data` attribute type because SF symbols are displayed using an `Image View`. I’m looking for a way to take an SF symbol from a SwiftUI `View`  and store it in the  `Core Data` Model. I also want to be able to retrieve that stored `Entity` attribute from my `Core Data` model and display it in any SwiftUI views I might choose.

How can I do this?

Comment: show us the code you have tried so far. You could get the data from SF symbol or you could just store the symbol's name as a string.

Comment: Yeah I just store the symbol name

Comment: You’ll never need to store the image itself, just the name. The name is a String. Retrieve the name String from Core Data and display the symbol in the usual way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual visual data for each SFSymbol is provided by the operating system and is referenced by the symbol’s name. As such, you do not need to create a copy of that data and store it in your Core Data model. You can always get the same image data back from the system by specifying the same name you used to initially display the symbol in the image view.

So, you can just add a String property to your entity, such as symbolName, to reference the SF Symbol.